# How to show(echo) max-width: 50% in browser in html code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I echo the value in a style value for instance here:

```
style="max-width:50%;"
```

I want to see the value in (max-width) in the html page when I run the code in a browser. I want to see it when I change the size of the page so I can see errors easily.

This thing is implemented in a browser when you inspect the page, but it is handy to see it without opening the inspector, because its difficult to see values screen when the inspector window is visual and takes too much windowspace.

I've tried to find a solution here but with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>paralyze website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-paralyze navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-brand">
        <img style="max-width:50%; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -7px;"
         src="pictures/paralyze-248x41.png" >

    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: example]

The picture demonstrates which value I want to show. Not exactly the one I want here, but I want you to know the idea what value/numbers I want to show.

Comment: didnt get your question..what was that?

Comment: Just detach or move the inspector...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsfiddledemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/amrk5tx1/2/)

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.width').html($('img').width());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-paralyze navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <p class="width"></p>
            <img style="max-width:50%; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -7px;" src="http://paralyze.se/sizebrowser.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dowomenfart!, that was just the thing I was looking for! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The attachment can't be opened, but you can use jquery to query the max-width value of an element id or a class or whatever other selector you want, using the **css method**.

Example:
If you have an html whose id is "xxx", then the following will do:

```
$("#xxx").css("max-width");
```

If your html element should be selected via a class value, then use:

```
$(".yourClassNameHere").css("max-width");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should i write it in the html code, echo "$(".yourClassNameHere").css("max-width");" or? The link to picture is working now.

Comment: If you are using google chrome, just open the console (F12), paste $(".yourClassNameHere").css("max-width"); and you will see the value (don't forget to provide the correct class name or id, according to your code)

Comment: I do not know where you want to use this value, do you want it to be added to the html ? Where in the html ?

Comment: ok, but I want to show it live when i change the browser size, I want to have this code updated like in the browser, but by my own code in html. By echo function.